# Determine whether or not $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ (assume that the operation of $H$ is the same as that of $G$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to answer the question:

> Determine whether or not $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ (assume that the operation of $H$ is the same as that of $G$).
>
> $$G=\langle\mathbb{R}, +\rangle,\ H=\{\log(a): a \in \mathbb{Q},\ a>0\}.$$

So I know for subgroups, you need to show closure under addition and closed with respect to inverses.

So for the first condition:

1. I said let $S \in G$ where $S=\{\log(b): b \in \mathbb{Q}, b>0\}$.

Therefore:

$$ H+S=\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab).$$

Since $ab \notin H+S$. Then $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

I'm having difficulties with inverse. So let's say that I decided to start with inverse instead rather than addition, how would I proceed? I understand the idea of inverse but I do not how to work with logs.

I know the inverse of log in general is $b^y=x$ for $\log_b(x)=y$ but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, regarding additive closure-
$$\log(a)+\log(b) = \log(ab) = 0 + \log(ab) = \log(1) + \log(ab) \in H+S$$
As for the inverse, functional inverse and inverse as a subgroup are very different things. Here, the operation is addition, and the additive identity is $0$. So, given an element $\log(a)$ in $H$, additive inverse should be $\log(b)\in H$, such that
$$ \log(a)+\log(b) = \log(ab) = 0 = \log(1)$$
As $a>0$ and $a\in \mathbb{Q}$, $\log(\frac{1}{a})$ is the required inverse.

Comment: Alright. I understand the inverse part but why was it necessary to show for the additive closure part for: log(ab)=0+log(ab)?

Comment: Just trying to bring to your attention that $\log(ab) \in H+S$.

Comment: What is S? And why are you showing the sum to be in a sum?

Comment: I'm assuming that S is another subgroup in G. so when H+S are added, the end result will be in H+S.

Comment: @CSil Why? That is not generally how you show something to be a subgroup.

Comment: Don't you have to show closure under the operation and that it has an inverse?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you know the group homomorphism, you can do better. Define $f:(\mathbb Q^+,\cdot)\to (\mathbb R,+)$ by $f(x)=\log x$, where $\mathbb Q^+$ is the group of all positive rationals under multiplication. Show that $f$ is indeed a homomorphism. Hence conclude that $H=$Range $(f)=f(\mathbb Q^+)$ being the homomorphic image of the group $\mathbb Q^+$, is a subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+).$